# Mover janela bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou usando o seguinte código pra mover janelas bootstrap:

```
$('#divform').modal({ 
    keyboard: false,
    show: true
});
//Jquery draggable
$('#divform').draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

Ou seja, tenho que fazer uso do jquery explicito pra mover a janela, gostaria de saber se o bootstrap dá esse recurso sem precisar o jquery.

Comment: Não, se você verificar a documentação do bootstrap ele mesmo diz que utiliza o jQuery para dar vida aos componentes.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/  "Traga componentes Bootstrap para a vida com mais de uma dúzia de costume plugins jQuery. Facilmente incluir todos eles, ou um por um."

Comment: Não, você precisa utilizar o jQuery para fazer isso com o bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap até o momento é super dependente de recursos do jQuery. Recomendo que vá para o site e busque plugins referentes para casos específicos.

http://plugins.jquery.com/

Mas em si o jQuery já têm essa funcionalidade "crua" (assim como postado por você mesmo a função). Mas mesmo assim segue o exemplo que está no próprio site deles.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Me arraste!</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```